# parsing html data iphone xpath

Tags: objective-c, parsing, ios4, xpath

have this webpage http://www.westminster.ac.uk/schools/computing/undergraduate . I'm using hpple to retrieve data (just started learning about it). I want to specifically retrieve the href from he main page, how can i do this?

I have this line - "NSArray *elements = [xpathParser search:@"//a"];" is able to retrieve all of the href links within the page however how can i retrieve just the ones in the main content? e.g. "BSc Honors Busniess Information Systems"? whats the syntax for it?

Comment: What is main content? Can you provide sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all of the "main content" stuff is found underneath  elements with id attributes like "content_div_XXXX" where XXXX is some randomly generated sequence. You might be able to get at what you want using an XPath that looks something like:

```
//div[starts-with(@id,'content_div')]//a
```

You should be able to get something like this working, although you'd have to try it out and perhaps tweak it a bit to make it work precisely as you want. Refer to [W3Schools XPath page](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp) for a good set of XPath tutorials

Comment: That actually works pretty well i do have some questions. So from what i gather in the tutorial whatever is in '[]' is is used to filter data. So in this case, were looking for a 'div that has an element id and contains the word 'content_div'?.

Comment: The above XPath selects all <a> elements that have a <div> ancestor with an "id" attribute that starts with the string "content_div". The bracket notation is how you implement conditional checks. The '@" syntax is how you reference attributes. If you have an additional question please update the post.

Comment: Thanks, assuming that i want to retrieve all the text from this page (the page content - in text format) http://www.westminster.ac.uk/schools/computing/undergraduate/computer-games-development/bsc-honours-computer-games-development would the syntax be this?div[starts-with(@id,'content_div')] without the hyperlink //a? Also when you look at the format of the webpage (to see the elements etc), how do u do it? do u just use firefox/mozilla etc to look at the source code raw? or is there a way to see it in xml format? thanks..

Comment: If you want to select the text within the <a> element rather than the <a> element itself, use //div[starts-with(@id,'content_div')]//a/text(). To see the elements of the HTML for this web page, I typically just view source from my browser. However, if you want more robust ways to analyze the HTML most browsers have built-in developer tools or plugins to help with that.